# Extra HTML meta data tags in branch.io generated links

Tags: branch.io

We are using branch to generate dynamic links for our application. We are using these links on various social media platforms. Branch configuration options enables us to populate fixed set of open graph data. In case of videos it lets us set `og:video` but there is no way to set `og:video:type`. Due to this, video embedding doesn't work if you are using HTML5 videos as the default video-type for Facebook is `application/x-shockwave-flash`.

I tried passing extra data while configuring link but it doesn't translate to HTML meta tags that are scrapped by Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Branch link is scraped, Branch will return:
1st: any parameters that have been defined for the link;
2nd: any parameters that have not been defined for the link but that have been defined at the app level (in Social Media Display Customization on the Link Settings page);
and finally: any meta tags present on the web site specified in the Default URL ($fallback_url) page.

Thus, even though the Branch does not provide an explicit parameter for defining og:video:type, you should be able accomplish this by adding the meta tag to the web page you use as your $fallback_url.

Here is an example:

I start with the following link "https://ogt1.app.link/fallbackurltags" where I have set the parameters below (note that "" is shown because I did not set any OG parameters for the link). Note that I have set the $fallback_url:

```
{
"$desktop_deepview": "",
"$desktop_url": "",
"$fallback_url": "https://dwestgate.github.io/ExampleFallBackURL/",
"$marketing_title": "OG Tag Testing - fallback URL tags",
"$og_description": "",
"$og_image_url": "",
"$og_title": "",
"$one_time_use": "",
"~creation_source": 1,
"~feature": "marketing",
"~id": "357178398369800081",
"~marketing": true
}
```

"og:video:type=application/x-shockwave-flash" has not been seet anywhere on the Branch dashboard or as a link parameter.

I have added meta tags, however, to a simple web site I have created and assigned as the $fallback_url: https://dwestgate.github.io/ExampleFallBackURL/. Here is that web page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="title" content="Tag set by Fallback URL" />
  <meta name="description" content="Tag set by Fallback URL" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Tag set by Fallback URL" />
  <meta property="og:video:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/CsGYh8AacgY?version=3&autohide=1" />
  <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
  <meta property="og:video:width" content="160" />
  <meta property="og:video:height" content="90" />
  <title>Fallback URL with meta tags</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>All the action is in the meta tags - View Source</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

When I now browse to Facebook's Sharing Debugger (here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fogt1.app.link%2Ffallbackurltags) - voila: the og:video:type tag from that web page has been scraped. You can see the raw tags returned by clicking on the "Show All Raw Tags" button.

One thing that I did not mention that may screw things up: if there is a value provided for $og_url, only the tags for the website provided in this value will be present. The link https://ogt1.app.link/linktags, for example, has the following parameters:

```
{
"$marketing_title": "OG Tag Testing - per-link tags",
"$og_description": "OG Tags set at the link level",
"$og_image_height": "200",
"$og_image_url": "https://cdn.branch.io/branch-assets/1486394827408-og_image.png",
"$og_image_width": "200",
"$og_title": "Per-Link tags",
"$og_url": "https://dwestgate.github.io/ExampleFallBackURL/",
"$og_video": "https://www.youtube.com/v/CsGYh8AacgY",
"$og_video_height": "180",
"$og_video_width": "320",
"$one_time_use": "",
"~creation_source": 1,
"~feature": "marketing",
"~id": "357170874539266599",
"~marketing": true
}
```

In this situation the link parameters get overridden by the parameters in $og_url, as can be seen by checking the Facebook Sharing Debugger again (here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fogt1.app.link%2Flinktags):

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="title" content="Tag set by Fallback URL" />
<meta name="description" content="Tag set by Fallback URL" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Tag set by Fallback URL" />
<meta property="og:video:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/CsGYh8AacgY?version=3&autohide=1" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="160" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="90" />
```

I hope this provides sufficient clarity to allow you to populate whatever custom OG tags are needed.

Comment: Tried, Branch did't picked this meta tag from $fallback url. I doubt branch picks any other meta tags from $fallback_url except those specified in documentation.

Comment: Is it possible to have a $fallback_url and default $desktop_url and $android_url?

Comment: Yes, these are all separate parameters. Check out the full dictionary of p

Comment: I got confused by documentation. Won't adding $fallback_url will remove default values for $desktop_url and $android_url?

Comment: No, $desktop_url and $android_url will override $fallback_url with regards to redirection behavior. With regards to link scraping behavior, however, $fallback_url is the only URL that is used.

Comment: While creating a link, I am not specifying $android_url. It is picked from app level settings. Will this behavior change after using $fallback_url?

Comment: No, it should not. $fallback_url is the "url of last resort." If you set $android_url at either the link or app level, those URLs will take precedence over the $fallback_url on Android devices.

Comment: Is there any way to add og meta data to a existing branch deep link ? I do not want to create a new branch link each time but I need to share a dynamic title and description in the branch deep link. @dwestgate

Comment: You can append parameters to existing Branch links. This will work for parameters other than Campaign, Channel, Feature, Tags, and Stage. See the docs here: https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/creating-links/other-ways/ios/#appending-query-parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to add [custom meta tags](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/creating-a-deep-link#section-custom-tags) according to branch documentation. Just put every meta tag inside it which aren't supported by default.

```
$custom_meta_tags: '{"og:video:type": "application/x-shockwave-flash"}'
```